# How to download visual studios 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How can i download visual studios 2012 full version.I am unable to find any downloadable link. Can you suggest me the website to download full version of vs 2012 or the link from where i can download the vs 2012?

Comment: This q is quite un appropriate since VS is a non-free IDE

Comment: Type "download visual studio 2012 full version" into google. It's the first result.

Answer (score 0):

You can download VS2012 directly from Microsoft website [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30682)

Comment: not working url